# Appending data into csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am appending data from the arrays into csv file with the headers. The headers are appearing after every iteration while they should only appear on the top.

```
x=pd.DataFrame({'1st':U_1, '2nd':U_2, '3rd':U_3, '4th':U_4, 
   '5th':U_5, '6th':U_6, '7th':U_7, '8th':U_8,  'Time 
     Stamp':start})
export_csv = x.to_csv (r'/home/pi/Frames/q8.csv', index = None, 
    mode='a', header=True)
```

This is the output in the csv file:

```
  1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th,8th,Time Stamp
  ,,,,,,,,1559839922.75
  1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th,8th,Time Stamp
  ,,,,,,,,1559839922.71
  1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th,8th,Time Stamp
  ,,,,,,,,1559839922.73
  1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,6th,7th,8th,Time Stamp
  ,,,,,,,,1559839922.98
```

Comment: Just turn `header=False`

Comment: It wouldnt solve the problem. The headers would not even appear at the top while I want headers to appear only at the top.

Comment: Then create your csv file with the header only, then append the data with `header=False`.

Comment: One note: `to_csv()` should not be assigned to a variable. `export_csv = x.to_csv (...` should just be `x.to_csv (...`

Answer (score 0):

Create your csv file with the header only:

```
import numpy as np

csvheader = x.columns.values
csvheader = csvheader.reshape(1, csvheader.shape[0])

np.savetxt('/home/pi/Frames/q8.csv', csvheader, delimiter='\t', fmt='%s')
```

then append the data with `header=False`:

```
for loop:
    x.to_csv (r'/home/pi/Frames/q8.csv', index = None, mode='a', header=False)
```